# Least $x$ Such That $\lfloor x^2\rfloor -\lfloor x\rfloor ^2=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

A friend recently texted me the following:

> Compute the least $x$ such that $\lfloor x^2\rfloor -\lfloor x\rfloor ^2=10$.

Is there a way to do what my friend is asking analytically? I graphed it on Desmos, and got $x\approx 5.91608$. I realized that this should be (and indeed appears to be) $\sqrt{35}$, as then we have $35-25=10$. To show this, I tried my typical way of solving floor problems, which is to break up $x=I+F$, where $I=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $F=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. After simplifications, I got $\lfloor F(2I+F)\rfloor =10$. But then upon any further manipulation, I get back the original equation. Is there some further manipulation I am not aware of that lets me solve this analytically? Or am I on the wrong track entirely? Should I perhaps try to prove that $\sqrt{35}$ is the least value of $x$ satisfying the above condition? Sorry if I’m missing something obvious.

Comment: Least real number. Why? Do negative values mess it up? I’m looking on Desmos, but it looks like $\lfloor x^2\rfloor -\lfloor x\rfloor ^2\le 0 \forall x<0$.

Comment: No, just for the proof. Then prove for all real numbers $x<\sqrt{35}$ that the expression is $<10$.

Comment: Okay. Then I’ll see what I can do in terms of a proof. I’ll leave the question open, though, in case there’s some other solution or something.

Comment: Sure, leave it open. But try to solve it yourself. That's much better for you than copying someone's solution.

Comment: Of course. I would rather see multiple solutions to one problem than just one.

Comment: can you take advantage of the fact that $x = \lfloor x \rfloor +h$ with $h\in [0,1)$? and also of the fact that  $\lfloor{\lfloor x \rfloor +n} \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor +n$ with $n$ an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x = I+ F \qquad (I \in \mathbb Z, \quad 0 \le F < 1).$$

$$\lfloor 2IF+F^2\rfloor =10 \tag{A.}$$

A quick check shows that $I$ needs to be positive.

Let's first consider what happens when

$$F^2 + 2IF = 10 \tag{B.}$$

By the quadratic equation, 
$$F = \dfrac{-2I+\sqrt{4I^2+40}}{2} 
    = -I+\sqrt{I^2+10}$$

This clearly implies $F \ge 0$. We also need

\begin{align}
   F &< 1 \\
   -I+\sqrt{I^2+10} &< 1 \\
   \sqrt{I^2 + 10} &< I + 1 \\ 
   I^2 + 10 &< I^2 + 2I + 1 \\
   10 &< 2I + 1 \\
   I &\ge 5
\end{align}

Which leads, unsurprisingly, t0 $x = \sqrt{I^2+10}$ with the restriction $I \ge 5$.

For $I = 5$, we get $F = -5 + \sqrt{35}$. So $x = \sqrt{35}$.

$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor -\lfloor x\rfloor ^2 = 35 - 25 = 10$

In general, there will be a solution when

$$10 \le \lfloor 2IF+F^2\rfloor < 11$$

So our more general equation must have the form

$$ F^2 + 2IF = 10 + \epsilon$$

where $0 \le \epsilon < 1$. Then we would get

$$F = -I+\sqrt{I^2+10 + \epsilon}$$

and $$x = \sqrt{I^2+10 + \epsilon}$$

where $0 \le \epsilon < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

I hid most of the steps in "spoiler" sections so you can mouse over them to see part of the answer without showing everything.

We can rule out $x < 0,$ since

> if $x < 0$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq x < 0$ and therefore $\lfloor x\rfloor^2 \geq x^2 \geq \lfloor x^2\rfloor.$

For $x > 0,$ we have $x < \lfloor x+1\rfloor,$
from which $x^2 < \lfloor x+1\rfloor^2$
and therefore $\lfloor x^2\rfloor < \lfloor x+1\rfloor^2.$
It follows that

> $$\lfloor x^2\rfloor - \lfloor x\rfloor^2 < \lfloor x+1\rfloor^2 - \lfloor x\rfloor^2 = 2\lfloor x\rfloor + 1.$$

So

> you can have $\lfloor x^2\rfloor - \lfloor x\rfloor^2 \geq 10$ only if $2\lfloor x\rfloor + 1 > 10,$ which implies $\lfloor x\rfloor > 4.5,$ which implies $\lfloor x\rfloor\geq 5.$

So now you just need to prove that

> $\lfloor x^2\rfloor - \lfloor x\rfloor^2 < 10$ for $5 \leq x < \sqrt{35}.$

Comment: In the spoiler sections, MathJax isn’t formatting anything. I’ve had a problem with that as well (on Puzzling Stack Exchange, but still). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It formats fine for me. On other pages I sometimes notice that it fails to format theh MathJax in an answer. Sometimes reloading the page helps.

Comment: I think the problem is on mobile. I'm looking at it on my computer now, and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Interesting. I have noticed that the comments never format MathJax on mobile (unless you click on the option to do the formatting for an individual comment). Now this appears to be another case where the mobile doesn't do the formatting right away, and I guess there is probably not the "format in MathJax" option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \rfloor−\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{10} \\ $$
$$\ast \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{10}+\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}} =\left[\mathrm{10};\mathrm{11}\right) \\ $$
$$\ast\ast \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right)\right)^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{2}\lfloor{x}\rfloor\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right)+\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right)^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}} =\lfloor{x}\rfloor\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{2}\right)+\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $$
$$\ast\ast\ast \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{2}\right)+\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right)=\left[\mathrm{10};\mathrm{11}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{2}\right)=\left(\mathrm{9};\mathrm{11}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\frac{\left(\mathrm{9};\mathrm{11}\right)}{\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{2}\right)}=\left[\mathrm{5};\infty\right) \\ $$
$$\ast\ast\ast\ast \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\left[\mathrm{10};\mathrm{11}\right)+\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $$
$${x}_{{MIN}} =\sqrt{\mathrm{10}+\mathrm{5}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\sqrt{\mathrm{35}} \\ $$

Comment: This is incorrect. $\sqrt{35}\approx 5.916$, while the value you give has $6\frac{5}{6}\approx 6.833$, and I asked for the least real number $x$ that fulfilled my condition. I haven't checked to see exactly where you went wrong, but you did somewhere.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll reevaluate